# Redirect to a page even with typing error

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

I am looking for a solution that would allow a redirection when one character in the URL path is missing.

The example below is simple, but in my case I have URL with longer paths and sometimes complicated to write. I want to find a solution to handle typing errors, I mean still redirect when they happen.

**Example:**

- http://example.com/helo redirects to http://example.com/hello
- http://example.com/hell redirects to http://example.com/hello
- http://example.com/ello redirects to http://example.com/hello
- http://example.com/hllo redirects to http://example.com/hello

I know about apache redirection, and already tried something like :

```
RewriteRule ^helo$              hello.php
RewriteRule ^hell$              hello.php
RewriteRule ^ello$              hello.php
RewriteRule ^hllo$              hello.php
RewriteRule ^hello$             hello.php
```

But I would like something automatic, for cases that I didn't note, such as /hell...

The best would be to do that with regexp in apache, but I'm quite bad in apache htaccess management.

I thought also I could do that in my 404 page, with some JS code, and redirect if the page url is one character far from elements on a list.

So what do you think ? Would there be a simpler solution than that horrible JS redirect ?

Comment: Be warned that down this path, ambiguities are waiting to happen. As well as the burden to keep supporting these "redirects" to point to the same thing when someone programs one in. I seriously doubt this guesswork is worth the effort.

Comment: To get any answer, define "one or two characters are wrong". Missing? Different? Misplaced (how much)? What about extra characters?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev : I will edit the post to answer your questions :)

Comment: @anubhava : hello is not a valid filename, the php file is the target and will display a page. I am doing a redirection using Apache htaccess (RewriteRule ^hello$             hello.php)

Comment: No regex can be used to correct the spelling. However using regex you can take care of **known wrong spellings**

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a limited set of known  URLs  to serve? Then you could maybe calculate the [edit distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) with those when you hit a 404, return the closest with a threshold to avoid ridiculous matches?

Comment: Thanks for the link on edit distance :) I thought there could be another solution than the "dirty" redirection when 404 is hit. Like something inside the htaccess. (I noticed some uses of regexp in htacess files)